# Is it safe to wrap Application.Run(new Form()) with a using(...) { } statement?

Tags: c#, c#-3.0, singleton, using-statement

I am using an external API to interface to a FireWire Camera. The API is propably written in C++ but thankfully it brings its own .NET wrapper DLLs. The API requires the following procedure:

```
ApiResource.Init();
// ... use the ressource here ...
ApiResource.CloseAll();
ApiResource.Release();
```

Because I need some specific handling code I decided to write a wrapper class for this. I need to keep the ressources open while my Form is open because of Event Handlers, etc. So I thought to make the wrapper easier to use I'd make it a singleton implementing `IDisposable` so I can wrap it in a `using` statement. The reason I want a Singleton is to have a controlled and limited way of calling the required API functions:

```
class Wrapper : IDisposable {
  private Wrapper _instance;
  public Wrapper Instance
  {
    get
    {
      if(_instance == null)
        _instance = new Wrapper();
      return _instance;
    }
  }

  private Wrapper ()
  {
    ApiResource.Init();
    _disposed = false;
  }

  // Finalizer is here just in case someone
  // forgets to call Dispose()
  ~Wrapper() {
    Dispose(false);
  }

  private bool _disposed;

  public void Dispose()
  {
    Dispose(true);

    GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
  }

  protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
  {
    if(!_disposed)
    {
       if(disposing)
       {
       }
       ApiResource.CloseAll();
       ApiResource.Release();
       _instance = null;
       log("Wrapper disposed.");
       _disposed = true;
    }
  }
}
```

The way I want to use it is this:

```
using(Wrapper.Instance) {
  Application.Run(new Form());
}
```

I'm quite new to C# so I am very unsure of a couple of things:

1. Will `Dispose()` always be called in the above `using(Singleton.Instance) { ... }`? My logging suggests "yes", but I'm unsure...
2. Is it safe to wrap `Application.Run(...)` with a `using`-statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to both of your questions is *yes*:

- `Dispose()` will always be called when the `using` block ends, unless `Wrapper.Instance` was `null` when the block began.
- It is perfectly safe to wrap the call to `Run()` in a `using` block.